# Guarantee an authentic geolocation

Tags: javascript, security, geolocation

I'm using Javascript geolocation API to feed a REST service with the position.
I can't figure out how I can have the guarantee that the supplied position is authentic, not a hacked one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

It's exactly the same as with *any other* user input: you can't trust it.

You can *try* to cross-verify it with something like the geo-ip database, but that is very coarse and error prone as well (i.e. you might be able to find out if a given country is wrong, but you won't be able to find out that he positioned himself at the wrong street within a city).

Answer (score 0):

You're dependent on untrusted user data and the problem with this is that, well, you can't trust it! From a security perspective, all untrusted data should be validated against a whitelist of acceptable ranges so the best you're going to be able to do is define what those ranges are (min and max long and lat). Beyond that, there's simply way you can guarantee that you've been provided with authentic values.